# Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access object on computer

Tags: hyper-v

I read up a bit on this error and i'm still not sure why i'm getting it when trying to run `$a = Get-VMSystemSwitchExtensionPortFeature -FeatureId 776e0ba7-94a1-41c8-8f28-951f524251b5`

I have virtualization enabled and in BIOS and Hyper-V platform and tools enabled in windows features.

Also tried using `MOFCOMP %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsVirtualization.V2.mof` to rebuild.

And i ran as admin.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the Hyper-V Role (and all dependencies), rebooting the host and installing the role once again usually helps with such kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V VMM service fails and Event ID 14050 is logged when dynamicportrange is changed.
Resolved running the script from Microsoft:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v-vmm-service-fails-event-id-14050